# Помогите понять как должна выглядеть входная строка

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть такое регулярное выраженые **^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})$** что сказано:Элементы в поле Inventory нужно вводить как список, разделяемый запятыми; при этом ожидается, что элементы будут представлять собой номера деталей в соответствии с номенклатурой;

Я не пойму какая должна быть строка подходящая шаблону **^\D?(\d{3})\D?\D?(\d{3})\D?(\d{4})$**.
Я использовал  сайт для теста:[Тест регулярных вырвный](https://regex101.com/r/5vRVOe/3).

Откуда я взял шаблон данной статьи:[Применение в WPF сложных бизнес-правил к вводу данных](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/archive/msdn-magazine/2010/june/msdn-magazine-input-validation-enforcing-complex-business-data-rules-with-wpf)

Проблема в том данной статье исходников кода нет(перехожу по ссылке она не работает),приходиться все вручную делать и бывает такое код не конца дописан.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например такая:
`D1113334444` или такая `1113334444`

Справа на сайте есть объяснение, что ищет каждый из элементов регулярного выражения.
Ваше регулярное выражение читается так:

Найди мне строку, которая:

1. Возможно начинается не с цифры `^\D?`
2. После чего помести три идущие следом цифры в первую группу `(\d{3})`
3. Возможно в строке будет еще две не цифры `\D?\D?`
4. После чего помести три идущие следом цифры во вторую группу `(\d{3})`
5. Возможно в строке будет еще одна не цифра `\D?`
6. После чего помести четыре идущие следом цифры в конце строки в третью группу `(\d{4})$`

Comment: Спасибо я думал что это список заказов. В статье это очень плохо обязательно(( Я до конца не понял был логику.